# Сериализация объекта и его хранение - PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Добрый вечер, господа, такая задача:

Делаю модуль чата на ajax, для пользователей некой CMS.

Реализован некий класс `User`, который наследуется от абстрактного класса `Users`.

Когда пользователь впервые подключается к чату, то для него создается экземпляр класса, в котором определяется его ФИО, аватарка, и много других данных, которые используются.

В этом же классе, реализовано подключение к БД, добавление сообщения, и проверка на существование новых непрочитанных сообщений и их вывод, и другие вычисления.

Дело в том, после того как пользователь в первые к чату подключился, ajax'ом сек 2-3 сек, отправляются запросы на сервер, и для каждого запроса, каждый раз создается экземпляр класса.

Понятное дело, что это не хорошо, для чего каждый раз делать те вычисления, определение ФИО и т.д. каждый раз?

Есть мысль, создать паттерн `singleton`, который будет после инициализации будет храниться в сессии, а после десериализация, восстанавливать просто подключение к БД и дальше пользоваться объектом.

Подскажите пожалуйста, это нормально хранить сериализованный объект в сессии для такой задачи? или может использовать какие-то временные таблицы в БД?
Или что делают в таких случаях?

Comment: вы прадва собираетесь сэкономить несколько микросекунд?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.serialization.php

Answer (score 2):

> В этом же классе, реализовано подключение к БД, добавление сообщения,
>   и проверка на существование новых непрочитанных сообщений и их вывод,
>   и другие вычисления.

Лучше все это хранить в отдельных классах, так как, например, подключение к БД может понадобится и в других скриптах чата.

> это нормально хранить сериализованный объект в сессии для такой
>   задачи?

Нормально, но вы должны понимать, что в этом случае, при изменении пользовательских данных, например имени, эти изменения не отобразятся в вашем чате. На мой взгляд лучше оставить так, как есть сейчас, т.е. каждый раз создавать экземпляр класса и не боятся этого, так как после выполнения PHP-скрипта все равно эти данные будут удалены из памяти. А думать об оптимизации стоит по мере наступления проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

Если получение данных отражается на производительности или как-то заметно, можно использовать кэширование. Создания PHP объекта не стоит бояться, это не ресурсоемкое действие. Посмотрите любой современный фреймворк, тот же Yii без кэширования схемы бд при создании модели запрашивает структуры таблиц и строит сущности. 
Время кэширования можно установить на несколько минут, либо навсегда. В последнем случае запросов в бд будет наименьшее количество, но при обновлении профиля стоит очищать или перезаписывать кэш записи. Так же не стоит рассчитывать на кэш, как на надежный источник данных. В любой момент данные из кэша можно потерять, если это какой-нибудь memcache

Comment: чувак делает чат

Comment: @Ипатьев И что? Кто запрещает кэшировать профили пользователей для чата?

Answer (score 2):

> В этом же классе, реализовано подключение к БД, добавление сообщения,
>   и проверка на существование новых непрочитанных сообщений и их вывод,
>   и другие вычисления.

Так делать не рекомендуется. Почитайте про [принцип единственной ответственности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Кстати, вот как раз подключение к БД имеет смысл реализовывать как `singleton`

> Реализован некий класс User, который наследуется от абстрактного
>   класса Users.

Были причины так сделать? Кто нибудь еще наследует от `Users`?

> Дело в том, после того как пользователь в первые к чату подключился,
>   ajax'ом сек 2-3 сек, отправляются запросы на сервер, **и для каждого**
>   **запроса, каждый раз создается экземпляр класса.**

У вас явные проблемы с архитектурой приложения. Вы пытаетесь бороться с последствиями, вместо того, что бы разобраться с причиной.

> Есть мысль, создать паттерн singleton

Для описываемой вами задачи не нужен singleton. Почему вы решили, что именно он вам поможет? Чем не устраивает обычный класс? Его можно с тем же успехом сериализовать.

Answer (score -4):

> Подскажите пожалуйста, это нормально хранить сериализованный объект в сессии для такой задачи?

Нет.

На практике это в принципе очень редко бывает оправдано,
а уж в данной конкретной ситуации и вовсе не имеет смысла.

Я бы написал "создаст больше проблем, чем решит" но это подразумевало бы, что мы здесь решаем какую-то проблему. Но в том-то и дело, что проблема эта воображаемая, высосанная из пальца. В программировании очень важно заниматься решением реальных проблем, а не тех, которые рисует воображение.

Comment: Разверните, пожалуйста, свою мысль: по каким именно причинам это не нужно и не работает.

Comment: Это не только нужно, но еще и работает - все зависит от обстоятельств и поставленной задачи! Неужели вы и в правду думаете, что хранить сериализованный объект в сессии - "не нужно" и "не будет работать"?

Comment: @Miron, влезая в дискуссию, следует читать не только заголовок вопроса.

Comment: После редактирования ваш ответ выглядит намного лучше, а то "нет, потому что я так сказал", без аргументов, смотрелся весьма непрофессионально.